# Android how to get image via putExtra

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi I need a little help with understanding how to send image `uri` via `intent.putExtra()` so I can change the source of another activity with `intent.getExtra()`.

So basically I'm trying to send from **Activity1** `intent.putExtra("R.drawable.image");`  to **Activity2** and show the image.

I'm trying to do it like this :

Activity1:

```
intent.putExtra("image_url","R.drawable.image");
```

Activity2:

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    String image_link = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url");
```

and I don't know how to set it as background to image.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you pass `R.drawable.image` as a String?

Comment: It's an `int`, so just pass it as an `int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Activity1:

```
intent.putExtra("image_url",R.drawable.image);
```

Activity2:

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    int image_link = getIntent().getIntExtra("image_url", R.drawable.default);
```

Now you have the resource id as an int and you can use it:

```
imageView.setImageResource(image_link);
```

Comment: Maybe I am being dumb but what is R.drawable.default? When you pass R.drawable.image and get the image via getIntExtra and set imageView.setImageResource I would presume the image would be the passed drawable R.drawable.image ? New to Android :-(

Answer (score 0):

wrong answer you have given buddy!!!!
error at  int image_link = getIntent().getIntExtra("image_url");
we have to given atleast two parameters in getIntExtra("image_url",defaultvalue);

Answer (score 0):

Frist Java Class:

```
i.putExtra("image_url",R.drawable.mumbai_activity);
```

Second Java Class:

```
Intent i = getIntent();

int image_link = i.getIntExtra("image_url","Default Image");
            imgvw.setImageResource(image_link);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] flag_image={R.drawable.bd,R.drawable.nepal,R.drawable.india};
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageGallary.class);
intent.putExtra("image",flag_image[1]); //flag_image array index position 1 pass by nepal image send  
startActivity(intent);

//ImageGallary Empty activity

imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
int image_link =getIntent().getIntExtra("image",0);  //0 is default value
imageView.setImageResource(image_link);
```