# sending an image to another activity, image not showing up no errors

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, imageview

So I sent some text to another activity, and I'm trying to send an image now. No errors at all and did some research ([Android how to get image via putExtra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378872/android-how-to-get-image-via-putextra)) however my image is not showing up. Wondering what I'm not including in my code to make the image appear. Thanks in advance.

//first activity

```
public class IntentsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(myListener);

}
// Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
private OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener() {
  // do something when the button is clicked
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondPage.class);
        String text = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString();

        ImageView Selection = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1));

        myIntent.putExtra("Text", text);
        myIntent.putExtra("img", R.drawable.icon);

        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 
        } 
    };

}
```

//Second Activity

```
public class SecondPage extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    //get extras
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    String text = b.getString("Text");

    //show text
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(text);

    //show image
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    int resource = getIntent().getIntExtra("img", 0);
    image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resource));

    Button btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), IntentsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        }   
    });
    }
}
```

//Some XML (nothing else would be relevant)

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/FirstLayout"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
</TextView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapWords" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

//logcat error from armand

```
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.colum.iam/edu.colum.iam.SecondPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at edu.colum.iam.SecondPage.onCreate(SecondPage.java:31)
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-12 12:05:36.024: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: where you are setting the resource for the image ?

Comment: You are passing a drawable over an intent. You should just get the drawable in the Secondpage

Comment: You are not even passing a drawable, but a drawable _identifier_, just an int value.

Comment: i don't see anything in your code that suggests that you are trying to show an image.

Comment: ok sorry guys i am new to mobile development (experiment class at our school) I apologize, that's why I'm on here though!

Comment: What's in your SecondPage line 31?

Comment: image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resource));

Answer (score 0):

You also need to get `img` key from Intent which hold drawable id in SecondPage Activity as:

```
    int drwable_id = bundle.getInt("img")); // get drawable id
   //show image
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(drwable_id));
```

Comment: This would be the correct way but I don't think this is necessary

Comment: @BigT : ` I don't think this is necessary` why ? because it may be possible OP want to show image in next Activity according to the result of prev Activity?

Comment: I also get no errors in code, but when program runs and i press the button, app crashes :(

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to set the image on SecondPage with the drawable instead of passing it in the Intent. Unless the image changes.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to accomplish is having an image in my first activity, and then send that image (along with text) onto a second page which will be a more descriptive version. I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do it, but this is what we are supposed to do.

Comment: @BigT: OP not passing drawable in intent. just passing id of drawable so i think  no issue in passing integer with intent to next activity

Comment: I get that. I just think it looks like an extra step to send id over through an Intent when the image won't change.

Comment: @BigT Yeah you're telling me man, I don't know why we're doing this, maybe just to prove that we can send the data through? I mean, maybe instead I'll send a bigger sized picture of what I want to send instead. But I have to figure this out first at least.

Comment: @user3081157 if this is a school thing then that is the reason exactly. To show you how to use Intents and what their purpose is in development

Answer (score 0):

Add this after initializing you image on SecondPage:

```
int resource = getIntent().getIntExtra("img", 0);
image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resource));
```

Comment: Code doesn't error, but when the app runs it crashes (would post the logcat but it's too long for a comment reply).

Comment: sorry, it crashes after I press the button (button loads second activity).

Comment: I can't find anything wrong but try initializing your intent like this: Intent myIntent = new Intent(IntentsActivity.this, SecondPage.class); and also, just use startActivity(myIntent); since you're not expecting a result from the second Activity.

Comment: Try using a View.OnClickListener too in your main Activity too.

Comment: I changed the syntax, still crashes when I press the button. I am running it on a 2.3.3, could that be why?

Comment: I do have the View.OnCLickListener (i think, here's what I have: import android.view.View.OnClickListener;)

Comment: Are you overriding the onClick?. It should look like -> 

 View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
  
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {}
 };

Comment: I was using an override! I just took it out and changed the syntax and still crashing :( I'll post the logcat on my OP (too long to post on here)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47345/discussion-between-user3081157-and-armandooj)

Answer (score 0):

you have to retrieve your image link, change your code to this:

```
//show image
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

int image_link = getIntent().getIntExtra("img", 0);

image.setImageResource(image_link);
```

Comment: you have to change this: `R.drawable.default` to a default image that you want to use or you can just put 0